# Shrink DB by replacing data with NULL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Azure SQL DB that stores photos in varchar(MAX) that are uploaded from a PowerApp during a sign-in / out process. The DB is growing quickly. I don't need the old pictures but I want to keep old records for in / out times. I thought I could shrink or make re-usable space by replacing the photo data with a NULL. However in testing it seems the DB is growing not shrinking when I do this. I can confirm the fields are becoming NULL but DB is growing as I do this.
This is what I ran:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Daily Activity Attendance]
SET Signature = NULL, Photo = NULL, SigninSig = NULL, SigninPhoto = NULL
WHERE [AttendanceDate] < '2019-03-20'
```

Is this just a bad idea or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is growing, your data files or your log files?

Comment: Initially the data from adding new photos. While clearing with nul I don't know. Possibly logs. This is on Azure and I just see stats on space usage allocated.

Answer (score 0):

To compact your LOB pages you should run an `ALTER INDEX` command and include the option `WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION =  ON)`

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the growth - it may be worth monitoring the ***UNDOCUMENTED*** DMF : `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations` to see what is happening to your rows as you change the value to NULL

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'<your table name>'),1,1,'limited');
```